# Is the domain space in Lusin's theorem required to be Hausdorff?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

I'm reading a general [version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543258/second-countability-in-lusins-theorem?rq=1) of Lusin's theorem, i.e.,

> If $\mu$ is a finite Radon measure on $X$, and $Y$ is a second countable topological spaces, then for any Borel-measurable function $f:X\to Y$ and any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a **compact** set $K\subseteq X$ such that $\mu(X\setminus K)<\epsilon$ and $f\rvert_K$ is continuous.

In above theorem, I assume that $X$ is **Hausdorff**. This assumption is standard in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Definitions) of Radon measure. The versions in Folland's *Real analysis: modern techniques and their applications*, and in Rudin's *Real and complex analysis* both assume this condition.

However, I have recently encountered a version in which $X$ is **not** assumed to be Hausdorff. This version is from Santambrogio's [*Optimal transport for applied mathematicians*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-20828-2). It is quoted verbatim as follows:

---

Let us be more precise: take a topological space $X$ endowed with a finite regular measure $\mu$ (i.e. any Borel set $A \subset X$ satisfies $\mu(A)=\sup \{\mu(K): K \subset A, K \text{ compact} \}=\inf \{\mu(B): B \supset A, B \text{ open}\}$ ). The arrival space $Y$ will be supposed to be second-countable (i.e. it admits a countable family $\left(B_i\right)_i$ of open sets such that any other open set $B \subset Y$ may be expressed as a union of $B_i$; for instance, separable metric spaces are second-countable).

**Theorem (weak Lusin)** - Under the above assumptions on $X$, $Y$, $\mu$, if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is measurable, then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a compact set $K \subset X$ such that $\mu(X \setminus K)<\varepsilon$ and the restriction of $f$ to $K$ is continuous.

**Proof** - For every $i \in \mathbb{N}$, set $A_i^{+}=f^{-1}\left(B_i\right)$ and $A_i^{-}=f^{-1}\left(B_i^c\right)$. Consider compact sets $K_i^{\pm} \subset A_i^{\pm}$such that $\mu\left(A_i^{\pm} \backslash K_i^{\pm}\right)<\varepsilon 2^{-i}$. Set $K_i=K_i^{+} \cup K_i^{-}$and $K=\bigcap_i K_i$. For each $i$ we have $\mu\left(X \setminus K_i\right)<\varepsilon 2^{1-i}$. By construction, $K$ is compact and $\mu(X \setminus K)<4 \varepsilon$. To prove that $f$ is continuous on $K$ it is sufficient to check that $f^{-1}(B) \cap K$ is relatively open in $K$ for each open set $B$, and it is enough to check this for $B=B_i$. Equivalently, it is enough to prove that $f^{-1}\left(B_i^c\right) \cap K$ is closed, and this is true since it coincides with $K_i^{-} \cap K$.

---

**My questions:**

1. The union of two compact sets is compact, so $K_i$ is compact. How do we conclude $K := \bigcap_i K_i$ is compact?
2. We have $f^{-1}\left(B_i^c\right) \cap K = K_i^{-} \cap K$. We know that $K_i^-$ is compact, but we don't know if it is closed. How do we conclude that $f^{-1}\left(B_i^c\right) \cap K$ is closed in $K$?

Comment: This is not something I've looked into, but a couple of references I've come across (e.g. about 18 years ago when looking at what I discuss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/61284/13130)) might be worth looking at (or googling their names and/or titles): **[1]** [*On the continuity of measurable functions in neighborhood spaces*](https://eudml.org/doc/114648) by Harry Max Schaerf (1947); **[2]** [*Lusin's theorem in an abstract space*](https://eudml.org/doc/29815) by Simmie Samuel Blankney (1969; see also [his thesis](https://dissexpress.proquest.com/dxweb/results.html?pubnum=6402863)).

Comment: In non-Hausdorff spaces, the intersection of compact sets need not be compact and compact sets need not be closed. A fun example is the topology $\tau=\{(a,\infty): a\in\mathbb R\}\cup \{\emptyset,\mathbb R\}$ where a set is compact if and only if it has a smallest element. This topology makes functions into $\mathbb R$ continuous if and only if they are lower semi-continuous.